# Spring JSF application flow

Tags: spring, jsf

I have previously written Spring MVC web applications where there is a front controller and we have a request mapping in each of the methods and this method in turn invokes a service implementation finally returning a view to the UI. Now when I design JSF applications am not able to understand the flow as such - 
This is what I currently have in my application:

1. The initial `index.html` redirects to the login page.
2. A backing bean for the login page which populates label values. Since it is an input form there is no other logic involved.
3. Once the user clicks on submit -> in the action method I have logic which will invoke the service(No.1) for authentication process and redirect the user to the home page by returning the name of the page
4. The home page displays various fields which are bound to a backing bean whose fields have to be populated by another web service call(No.2).

It is between the steps (3) and (4), I have a confusion. Previously in Spring I had an explicit mapping and I can "actually" control the logic in the front controller method. In JSF, I dont know whether the logic for No.2 web service call should be combined along with authentication call since I dont have a method to populate the beans.

It is as if I dont have the explicit control over the flow. I have read many articles trying to understand this but not am able to understand. Please provide me pointers and also some references which will actually explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you control the logic in JSF bean?Example usage with EJB

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    @EJB
    private AuthBean authBean;
    @EJB
    private UserSettings settingsBean;

    private String name, password;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        //do your initialization here
    }

    public String loginAction() {
        User user = authBean.authenticate(user, password);
        if(user != null) {
            UserSetting settings = settingsBean.getSettings(user.getId());
            return "home";
        }
    }
    //setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Yes if I have an action method - yes I can. Consider the above scenario for showing the home page - I don't have a matching method which I can use for populating the beans - In Spring I can have a requestmapping method which is exactly similar to the way a Servlet handles. But in JSF, I dont have it.

Comment: Just use bean's (post)constructor? Or am I misunderstanding the question? Spring is beyond me, namely.

Comment: @BalusC Havent used the (post)constructor before- But is this the preferred way for invoking the business logic corresponding to a request from UI?

Comment: No, its a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` which is called after the bean is created. Difference between this method and constructor is that this method makes sure that everything is correctly injected to bean before it is called.